# Android: Wait for a response by API before continue the execution using Retrofit

Tags: android, api, asynchronous, async-await, retrofit

I'm facing a problem on my android programming, I have an app that needs run some routines like scan some barcode.
Once that I scanned a barcode I will send the data of this barcode to my API, "wait" to get some information and after that do another things.

The problem it's when I call my API to get the information and after I try to use the information that was supposed to come from the API, I'm falling on a NULL Exception, see the code below:

My scan routine that is called every time I scan a barcode:

```
    // 1 - First Stage: Scan barcode of tank
    if(stageScannerTank == 1)
    {
        // Verify if the user scanned the correct Tank
        if (!resultScan.equals(expectedTank)) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Wrong Tank, scan the correct ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            stageScannerTank = 0;
            return;
        }


        // Get the tank information

        //new TanqueTask().execute(resultScan);

        **HERE IS MY PROBLEM, When I call the function below, I fill my tankMixPlant with data**

        getTankMixPlant(resultScan);

        ** I always fall into this IF **
        // If null information
        if(tankMixPlant == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error to read tank information", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

    }
```

getTankMixPlant, using Retrofit to call my service, it is working if I test out of my routine:

```
private void getTankMixPlant(String tankName){
    mService.getTankMixPlant(tankName).enqueue(new Callback<TankMixPlant>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TankMixPlant> call, Response<TankMixPlant> response) {
            tankMixPlant = response.body();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TankMixPlant> call, Throwable t) {
            // On failure show the error message to the User
            AlertDialog alert;
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Error");
            builder.setMessage("Error: " + t.getMessage());
            alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}
```

How can I wait tankMixPlant be filled up with data to continue my routine?

**UPDATES:**

I continue with the problem, but I changed some things that you can see below:
Now I get NullPointerException.

Now I verify if my object is null inside the onResponse method:

```
     private void getTankMixPlant(String tankName){
    mService.getTankMixPlant(tankName).enqueue(new Callback<TankMixPlant>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TankMixPlant> call, Response<TankMixPlant> response) {
            tankMixPlant = response.body();
            if(tankMixPlant == null) {
              Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error to read tank information", 
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              return;
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TankMixPlant> call, Throwable t) {
            // On failure show the error message to the User
            AlertDialog alert;
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Error");
            builder.setMessage("Error: " + t.getMessage());
            alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}
```

But when I try to verify some information about tankMixPlant:

```
        // Verify tank stage
        if(!tankMixPlant.getBlenderCode().equals("0") && tankMixPlant.getIngr() == 1)
        {
            getPackages(tankMixPlant.getRecipeNumber(), tankMixPlant.getBlenderCode(), tankMixPlant.getTankName());
            // 2 - Mix Packages: Scan package barcode
            stageScannerTank = 2;
        }

        if(!tankMixPlant.getIngrSAPNumber().equals("0") && tankMixPlant.getIngr() == 1)
        {
            getIngr(tankMixPlant.getRecipeNumber(), tankMixPlant.getTankName());
            // 3 - P.I Packages: Scan package barcode
            stageScannerTank = 3;
        }
```

My app crashes with this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.labtse.kibonapp, PID: 21519
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=114910, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 VirtualScreenParam=Params{mDisplayId=-1, null, mFlags=0x00000000)} (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.labtse.kibonapp/com.example.labtse.kibonapp.TabPagesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.labtse.kibonapp.model.TankMixPlant.getBlenderCode()' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5007)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5050)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:230)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1876)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.labtse.kibonapp.model.TankMixPlant.getBlenderCode()' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.labtse.kibonapp.MixPlantFragment.scanRoutine(MixPlantFragment.java:367)
                  at com.example.labtse.kibonapp.MixPlantFragment.onActivityResult(MixPlantFragment.java:399)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:151)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7165)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5003)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5050) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:230) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1876) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

My tankMixPlant class:

```
package com.example.labtse.kibonapp.model;

public class TankMixPlant {
    private String tankName;
    private String recipeNumber;
    private int idBatch;
    private String ingrSAPNumber;
    private String blenderCode;
    private short ingr;
    private boolean QRUN;
    private boolean QEND;
    private Boolean QDOSANDO;
    private Boolean CONF_ING;

    public TankMixPlant() {
    }

    public String getTankName() {
        return tankName;
    }

    public void setTankName(String tankName) {
        this.tankName = tankName;
    }

    public String getRecipeNumber() {
        return recipeNumber;
    }

    public void setRecipeNumber(String recipeNumber) {
        this.recipeNumber = recipeNumber;
    }

    public int getIdBatch() {
        return idBatch;
    }

    public void setIdBatch(int idBatch) {
        this.idBatch = idBatch;
    }

    public String getIngrSAPNumber() {
        return ingrSAPNumber;
    }

    public void setIngrSAPNumber(String ingrSAPNumber) {
        this.ingrSAPNumber = ingrSAPNumber;
    }

    public String getBlenderCode() {
        return blenderCode;
    }

    public void setBlenderCode(String blenderCode) {
        this.blenderCode = blenderCode;
    }

    public short getIngr() {
        return ingr;
    }

    public void setIngr(short ingr) {
        this.ingr = ingr;
    }

    public boolean isQRUN() {
        return QRUN;
    }

    public void setQRUN(boolean QRUN) {
        this.QRUN = QRUN;
    }

    public boolean isQEND() {
        return QEND;
    }

    public void setQEND(boolean QEND) {
        this.QEND = QEND;
    }

    public Boolean getQDOSANDO() {
        return QDOSANDO;
    }

    public void setQDOSANDO(Boolean QDOSANDO) {
       this.QDOSANDO = QDOSANDO;
    }

    public Boolean getCONF_ING() {
        return CONF_ING;
    }

    public void setCONF_ING(Boolean CONF_ING) {
        this.CONF_ING = CONF_ING;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

You must write this:

```
    if(tankMixPlant == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error to read tank information", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
```

Inside your `onResponse`, after the line `tankplant = ...`

Now, null exception will be eliminated if you are getting any data from the server.

Hope it helps.

**Update1:**

Write this:

```
    if(!tankMixPlant.getBlenderCode().equals("0") && tankMixPlant.getIngr() == 1)
    {
        getPackages(tankMixPlant.getRecipeNumber(), tankMixPlant.getBlenderCode(), tankMixPlant.getTankName());
        // 2 - Mix Packages: Scan package barcode
        stageScannerTank = 2;
    }

    if(!tankMixPlant.getIngrSAPNumber().equals("0") && tankMixPlant.getIngr() == 1)
    {
        getIngr(tankMixPlant.getRecipeNumber(), tankMixPlant.getTankName());
        // 3 - P.I Packages: Scan package barcode
        stageScannerTank = 3;
    }
```

in your `onResponse` method as shown below:

```
 private void getTankMixPlant(String tankName){
mService.getTankMixPlant(tankName).enqueue(new Callback<TankMixPlant>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<TankMixPlant> call, Response<TankMixPlant> response) {
       tankMixPlant = response.body();
       if(tankMixPlant == null) {
          Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error to read tank information", 
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          return;
       }

       ...... (Write Here)

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<TankMixPlant> call, Throwable t) {
        // On failure show the error message to the User
        AlertDialog alert;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Error");
        builder.setMessage("Error: " + t.getMessage());
        alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
});
```

Try it.

Comment: I did this like you said, but the behavior is the same, now the app crashes and says that my tankMixPlant is null when I try to use him in another piece of code.

Comment: Okay, So depending on the first question you asked, this solution solved it. Now I would like to understand few things. Firstly, Check what response you are getting and post it on your question. Secondly, Post your model class. Then, we shall continue ahead @MauricioReis

Comment: Thank you by your interest to help me @UmangBurman, I edited my question with the informations that you asked me. Hope that it helps.

Comment: Thank you by your help, now it's working, the problem it's because I am rewriting an app that was write in C# (Xamarin) to Java (Android), so I have the logic done and I was trying to just pass it without some modifications into Java. Now I did some modifications and it's working. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the retrofit call is done asynchronously, while the rest of your code isn't. That's why your data is `null`, since it's nor ready yet.

First of all, you have to remove the part of the code where you're checking for the "pending data", and move it inside your retrofit `onResponse` or somewhere else that'll be later called after the network response by using callbacks.

There are quite a few ways on exactly how you can do that. I'd suggest that you read [the documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) and some tutorials like [this one](https://www.dev2qa.com/retrofit-android-get-post-example/), and [this other one](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client).

Also, while you're making the retrofit call, it's best to display a loading message to the user, to keep him aware that you're making a network call and is waiting for the results.

Comment: I did this like you said, but the behavior is the same, now the app crashes and says that my tankMixPlant is null when I try to use him in another piece of code.
Thank's by the links I will see them.

Comment: Edit your question and show how the code looks now. The crash stack trace will be useful too.

Comment: I edited my question, now you can see what is ocurring.